# How to select text in several Text views at once?

Tags: swiftui

Here is a part of my view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("test1")
            Text("test2")
            Text("test3")
            Text("test4")
            Text("test5")
        }
        .textSelection(.enabled)
    }
}
```

I can select text in one view but not all the text at once. The views are more complex than this but this is the gist of it.

How can I make it so that I can select all the lines at once?
Thanks

Comment: seems like you only can select one TextView at a time. You could of course combine the strings into one Textview.

Comment: The problem is that I have different styles of text in each view. And using an AttributedString gets messy very quickly.

Comment: Can I ask what your requirements are? The obvious answer here is to just use one `Text(...)` with a `.multiline(..)` modifier attached to it, then format as desired.

Comment: Have you ever solved it?