# Multiple lines of text with alternating row colors (a Log view). How to select text across all lines?

Tags: swiftui, textselection, swiftui-text

I have a log view.
I want to display the log lines in alternating background colors.
I want to allow text selection across the whole log view. This can be done with `.textSelection(.enabled)` on a single `Text` view.

My problem is however, that to get the alternating background colors, I am breaking my string into lines and show them in a `ScrollView` (or `List`). When I add `.textSelection(.enabled)`, I can only select text in a single line at once.

**How can I select across the whole text?**

This is the code:

```
struct LogView: View {
    let lines: [String] = sampleText3.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(lines.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack() {
                        Text(lines[index])
                            .foregroundColor(adaptiveLineColor(lines[index]))
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(index % 2 == 0 ?  Color.gray.opacity(0.1) : Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                }
            }
            .textSelection(.enabled)
            .border(.gray.opacity(0.1),width: 1)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func adaptiveLineColor(_ line: String) -> Color {
        enum Tag: String {
            case task = "[Task]"
            case info = "[info]"
            case warning = "[warning]"
            case error = "[error]"
        }
        // TODO: Use switch
        if line.hasPrefix(Tag.task.rawValue) {
            return .green
        }
        if line.hasPrefix(Tag.info.rawValue) {
            return .primary
        }
        if line.hasPrefix(Tag.warning.rawValue) {
            return .yellow
        }
        if line.hasPrefix(Tag.error.rawValue) {
            return .red
        }
        return .primary
    }
}

let sampleText3: String = """
[Task] Process started. 30. Sep 2023, 21:26:20
[info] input file /someFolder/someData
[warning] invalid metadata
[error] error -1234
"""
```

Screenshot:

[image]

If I put the whole text in one multiline `Text`, `textSelection` works as expected, but I wouldn't know how to do the alternating background colors.

How can I solve this?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213338/how-to-select-text-in-several-text-views-at-once), but it has no solution.

Comment: If you want to select *all* of the text and not just *some* of the text, then you could provide a button to share (upload) the content that is shown.

Comment: Yes, the button to export the whole log, like a `ShareLink`, is something I will consider as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution (though this is a bit of a hack) is to draw twice. First draw the text as many separate `Text`s, each with their own background, and with a transparent foreground. Then, draw the entire string as a single `Text` as an overlay. The user can then select the overlay.

```
ScrollView {
    let attrText = makeAttributedString(sampleText3) // add all the different foreground colors as an AttributedString

    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        // lay out the texts with transparent foreground and alternating backgrounds
        let invisibleTexts = lines.map { Text($0).foregroundColor(.clear) }
        ForEach(lines.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            HStack {
                invisibleTexts[index]
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(index % 2 == 0 ?  Color.gray.opacity(0.1) : Color.black.opacity(0.1))
        }
    }
    .overlay {
        // lay out the selectable text in the same way
        HStack {
            Text(attrText).textSelection(.enabled).padding(.horizontal, 5)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .border(.gray.opacity(0.1),width: 1)
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, this works! When you say it a hack, do you think it has downsides?

Comment: @soundflix I'm creating many `Text`s that are invisible, and whose sole purpose is to display a background color. That is rather a waste, isn't it? A "non-hack" would be if SwiftUI has a dedicated API to "connect" the texts in different views together. I don't know of such a thing though.

Comment: Ok, I see; with a longer log, I notice the performance degradation when resizing the window.

Comment: I'm testing with a real log now and they have empty lines. These seem to add an offset across the overlay. When I add `.offset(y: -6)` inside of overlay, it is fixed until the first empty line. Then each empty line adds around 1 point of offset.

Comment: @soundflix hmm I didn’t expect that. I thought `Text` in a `VStack` would have the same layout as multiline text. I’d suggest first try to do `VStack(spacing:0)` and play around with the line spacing of the attributed string of that didn’t work.

Comment: @soundflix if that still doesn’t work, another idea  I can think of is to wrap a `NSTextView` and use text kit, but that would be a lot more complicated and needs more code.

Comment: If I use this text replacement: `let viewText = sampleText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n\\n*", with: "\n \n", options: .regularExpression)` and `.offset(y: -7)`, lines match perfectly (I'm testing with `.gray` instead of `.clear` background layer). There is just the small problem that my regex replaces any amount of empty lines with only 1 line of single whitespace instead of the correct amount. My regex skills might be lacking here.

Comment: Is there a reason to chose `.overlay` and not `ZStack` in this solution?

Comment: @soundflix No :) `overlay` is usually the first that comes to my head. The size of the overall view is determined by the view to which `overlay` is applied, whereas the size of a `ZStack`is determined by all the views in a `ZStack`, so I find the former easier to reason about. I don’t think `ZStack` makes a difference here, does it?

Comment: I tried it: with `overlay` I need `offset(y: -7)` inside for a perfect match of layouts. With `ZStack`I tried +1 and -1 and both are not perfect. Performance seems same.